# Записать исходный код страницы в файл через командную строку

Tags: windows, командная-строка

Есть список ссылок в файле на веб страницы.

Пример:

```
https://www.afisha.ru/movie/169165/
https://www.afisha.ru/movie/166566/
https://www.afisha.ru/movie/172377/
https://www.afisha.ru/movie/179525/
https://www.afisha.ru/movie/167039/
https://www.afisha.ru/movie/181150/
https://www.afisha.ru/movie/175849/
https://www.afisha.ru/movie/193044/
```

Вопрос:

Можно ли с помощью командной строки windows сохранить исходный код страницы в файл .html?

Прошу помощи в реализации.

Comment: Вам обязательно нужно через командную строку? Есть много софта на эту тематику.

Comment: ну конечно же, с помощью PS можно: **powershell -nop -c "Invoke-WebRequest -uri httрs://www.afisha.ru/movie/169165/index.html -OutFile c:\download\169165.html"**. Ежели совсем древняя версия PS: **powershell -nop -c "$web=New-Object System.Net.WebClient; $web.DownloadFile('httрs://www.afisha.ru/movie/169165/index.html','C:\download\169165.html')"**

Answer (score 0):

wget -r  адрес страницы. Попробуйте

Comment: 1. а зачем опция `-r`? 2. речь была про ms/windows.

Comment: К сожалению не работает.

Comment: @verstala, сначала установи его. Или curl.

Comment: Не понял. Что установить?

Comment: wget сначала нужно установить